# Partition Query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in MySQL database.

```
CustomerID  DateCompleted
1            2021-02-19 05:59:04
1            2021-03-19 05:59:04
2            2021-05-19 05:59:04
3            2021-01-19 05:59:04
```

I want to have a new column that inserts the previous order date for a customer ID. This is my query but gave me a syntax error:

```
SELECT
   DateCompleted,
   CustomerID,

   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY
   DateCompleted ASC) as customer_order_sequence,

   LAG(DateCompleted) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY
   DateCompleted ASC) as previous_order_date

   FROM  Order
   GROUP BY DateCompleted, CustomerID
```

Whats wrong with my Query?

Comment: show the syntax error and the MySQL version?

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: Your query was looked like working well except the `group by` part.

Comment: Version : 5.7.23-log,  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DateCompleted ASC) as customer_order_seque' a

Comment: window function will be supported after Mysql version 8.0, you can try to upgrade the version & try it

Comment: @D-Shih Cant update the version :/

Comment: I can't make new features magically appear in released versions :/  :-)